# Easiest way to track search terms with Google Analytics?

Tags: webforms, google-analytics

*My [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066974/tracking-visitors-search-terms-in-google-cse-with-google-analytics) was somewhat narrower than this one.*

I am interested to know how to track search terms in general. How would you install Google Analytics to simple form with a submit button (assuming there is only one field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Analytics, under *Profile Settings* enable site search (*Do Track Site Search*), and set the *Query Parameter* to the name of the input field. (And, of course, make sure that the tracking code was installed on the page the form's action points to.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the utm_term URL parameter in your URL you send to GA. 
Example: utm_term=running+shoes

You can submit to GA a URL as described here:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=24abd1518783c26f&hl=en

Comment: Can I enable different parameters by using this: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578 ? Something about campaigns?! Surprising that you can use it in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "enable different parameteres"

Comment: This is only applicable for *inbound* traffic from external paid search. This is NOT applicable for internal site search; if you do this for internal site search, you'll break Google Analytics and cause a new visit to be created on every search.